# Sql data in multiple rows - get output in one row

Tags: sql

I have a table in sql which looks like below. Basically typeid column determines which type of data it is like address, name, department etc. So, there are multiple rows in the table for one employee.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPAfT.png)

| ID | employee | Type id | column 1 | column 2 | column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | building 6 | null | New York |
| 2 | 1 | 6 | Adam | Smith |  |
| 3 | 1 | 7 | null | null | Finance |
| 4 | 1 | 8 | null | AS7836 | null |

is it possible to write a query to get an output for one employee in one row - like below ? Thanks.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJpRt.png)

| Emplyee | first name | Last name | department | payroll nu | Address | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | Smith | Finance | AS7836 | building 6 | New York |

Comment: I added tables containing the data from your images. Please avoid posting images of code as it makes it harder to help you.

Comment: This is for a legacy system so re-creating the table structure is not an option, I am afraid

Comment: Thanks D M. This is my first ever post and the site didn't let me add the tables.

Comment: Thanks Austin.  I did try self joins but am still getting multiple rows. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Monika No worries, I don't believe there is a table tool in the post editor but if you are interested in learning about the capabilities of markdown on StackOverflow, you can check out the [CommonMark Spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/). You can also click the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68010378/edit) link below your post to see the markdown I used to create the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of self joins to get your results:

```
select t.Employee
    , t.column1 first_name
    , t.column2 last_name
    , t2.column3 department
    , t3.column2 payroll_nu
    , t4.column1 address
    , t4.column3 city
from tbl t
inner join tbl t2
    on t.employee = t2.employee
    and t2.TypeID = 7
inner join tbl t3
    on t.employee = t2.employee
    and t3.TypeID = 8
inner join tbl t4
    on t.employee = t4.employee
    and t4.TypeID = 5
where t.employee = 1
    and t.TypeID = 6
```

Example Results:

[image: Example Results]