# Display four rows as one row (Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I have four columns and rows  with database how to display as one row with one column.

Example:

```
  > UID    TIME MIN     MON     MOUT        AIN       AINOUT
        > 14406  2022-08-7   ontime     -          -          -
          14406   2022-8-7      -      ontime      -          -
          14406   2022-08-07     -      -         ontime      -
          14406  2022-08-07     -       -         -          ontime
```

How to make some thin lik this with one uid

```
    > UID    TIME MIN     MON     MOUT        AIN       AINOUT
    > 14406  2022-08-7   ontime  on time    ontime   on time
```

Comment: `SELECT uid, time, time_search, min(min) as min, min(mout), as mout, min(ain) as ain, min(aout) as aout FROM yourtablename GROUP BY uid, time, time_search`.   (I hope I did get the fieldnames correct, if not please share the query you are currentl using)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sql data in multiple rows - get output in one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68010378/sql-data-in-multiple-rows-get-output-in-one-row)   (This shows a different way than my previous comment...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific case:

```sql
  SELECT d1.uid, DATE(d1.time) time, d1.min, d2.mout, d3.ain, d4.aout
    FROM devices d1, devices d2, devices d3, devices d4
   WHERE d1.min <> '' AND d2.mout <> '' AND d3.ain <> '' AND d4.aout <> '';
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You have to arrange your columns with this query:

```
 SELECT uid,time,time_search,min(min) as min,min(mout) as mout,min(ain) as ain,min(aout) as aout FROM db_tbl_name GROUP BY uid,time,time_search
```

This would work fine for your case to get multiple retundant data in one row

Comment: Dear ali thanks for your help but its still same

Comment: @MoJustNow its my pleasure to help you